# Retrieve element value of json in express node js

Tags: node.js, express

How to get the value of element from json array in express node js?

```
{"name":"aarti"}
```

I need to get the result :- `aarti`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.Also verify that Json object is there.It may be possible that data is coming in the form of String.So in that case use JSON.parse("whatever input is coming");

```
 var jSon ={"name":"aarti"}
 for(x in jSon){
    var value = json[x];
  }
```